# How to use pandas groupby to an unknown amout of columns?

Tags: python, pandas

I just want to know how it is possible to use this command `df.groupby(['column1', 'column2', 'column3']).size()` with a variable amount of columns.

Comment: Does anyone of you know if and how I can apply groupby to an dictionary?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can give groupby a list of columns.

```
grouper = ['column1', 'column2', 'column3']

df.groupby(grouper).size()
```

There is no difference between instantiating the list to give it as a function parameter or assigning it to a variable and using that in the function. You can change the columns of grouper dynamically.

Comment: Thank you very much, I already tried that but i unfortunately forgot to remove the squared brackets ```df.groupby([grouper]).size()``` .... ups :D. Nevertheless thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

If need grouping by all columns of `df` use:

```
df.groupby(df.columns.tolist()).size()
```

If need grouping by all columns without `ID` use [`Index.difference`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.difference.html):

```
df.groupby(df.columns.difference(['ID'], sort=False).tolist()).size()
```

Answer (score 1):

Given you previous question, you likely want to group by all columns except the ID (otherwise you would get only groups with single items):

```
cols = df.columns.drop(['ID']).tolist()
df.groupby(cols).size()
```

*NB. You can add in the list any other column name that needs to be excluded*